# Change compile configuration of package installation in brew

Tags: terminal, homebrew

How can I change the compiler configuration when I use brew install? I want to compile vim with +farsi using brew. But it seems that +farsi is not available options in brew:

```
$ brew install +farsi vim
Error: No available formula for +farsi
```

I also tried this command:

```
$ brew install vim --+farsi
==> Downloading http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/v/vim/vim_7.4.052.orig.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/vim-7.4.052.tar.gz
==> Patching
patching file src/auto/configure
patching file src/osdef.sh
patching file src/os_mac.h
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local --mandir=/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052/share/man --enable-multibyte --with-tlib=ncur
==> make
==> make install prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.4.052 STRIP=/usr/bin/true
```

But still +farsi is not compiled with vim:

```
[ben@thebeast ~/vim/vim74]$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Aug 24 2013 18:58:47)
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
-farsi
```

In fact the only options available are these:

```
$ brew options vim
--disable-nls
    Build vim without National Language Support (translated messages, keymaps)
--override-system-vi
    Override system vi
--with-client-server
    Enable client/server mode
--with-lua
    Build vim with lua support
--with-mzscheme
    Build vim with mzscheme support
--with-perl
    Build vim with perl support
--with-python3
    Build vim with python3 support
--with-tcl
    Build vim with tcl support
--without-python
    Build vim without python support
--without-ruby
    Build vim without ruby support
--HEAD
    install HEAD version
```

Does this means that only subset of configurations are available in brew?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `brew install vim` installs vim *7.4.052*
2. `vim --version` reports version *7.3*

From above observation it is clearly apparent that these are two different vims. By executing `vim --version` you are invoking vim supplied as part of OS X (you can check this by `which vim`, which is going to report */usr/bin/vim*, while brew-built programs are usually located under */usr/local* directory.

To edit vim formula you just execute `brew edit vim`, yet you do not need to do this just to get your desired farsi support. As you can see from [Vim Feature Table](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vimfeat.html), farsi support is included with any build compiled with `--with-features=big` or huge. As brew builds are compiled with `--with-features=huge`, they already contain farsi support.

> /usr/local/bin/vim --version
>   VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  1 2014 14:31:50)
>   MacOS X (unix) version
>   Included patches: 1-52
>   Compiled by Homebrew
>   Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
>   ⋮
>   +acl      +farsi      +mouse_netterm  +syntax
>   ⋮

To use brew-built version of vim you might like to alias it with `alias vim='/usr/local/bin/vim'`, or try any of [other options](https://superuser.com/questions/324616/how-should-i-set-the-path-variable-on-my-mac-so-the-hombrew-installed-tools-are).

Comment: which vim returns "/usr/local/bin/vim". This is the vim installed by brew not the vim installed  by OS X. However still when I execute "vim --version" I get -farsi. It seems like "brew install" does not listen to the edit file and does not compile it with huge option. Any idea how I can debug this?

Comment: @Dane Does `/usr/local/bin/vim --version` also show _-farsi_?

Answer (score 4):

You can edit the brew's formula for vim which is probably at `/usr/local/Library/Formula` and in file named `vim.rb`. You can edit this file and add your needed options in the lines where it execute the compilation process such as `system "make"` or

```
system "./configure", "--prefix=#{HOMEBREW_PREFIX}",
                      "--mandir=#{man}",
                      "--enable-multibyte",
                      "--with-tlib=ncurses",
                      "--enable-cscope",
                      "--with-features=huge",
                      "--with-compiledby=Homebrew",
                      *opts
```

I don't think that it just implement some of the options, brew dynamically creates the compile options according to the application's compilation process and makefiles.